# .NET Core 7 SignalR how to create time based stats update using DI

Tags: .net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-7.0

I have the following hub and I'm trying to determine how to set it up to send stats back to the client every 15 seconds using a DI based service to pull the data from my database. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to structure this logic to work.

```
[Authorize]
public class StatsHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        // this method call obviously won't work due to the paramters, not sure how to structure this
        GetStats();

        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    private void GetStats([FromServices] IQueueService queueService, [FromServices] TimerManager timerManager)
    {
        timerManager.PrepareTimer(async () => {
            var results = await queueService.GetStats();

            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SendQueueStats", results.Payload);
        }, 15000);            
    }
}
```

Here is the `PrepareTimer` method logic

```
private Timer _timer;
private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;
private Action _action;

public DateTime TimerStarted { get; set; }
public bool IsTimerStarted { get; set; }

public void PrepareTimer(Action action, int delayMS)
{
    _action = action;
    _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    _timer = new Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 1000, delayMS);
    TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
    IsTimerStarted = true;
}

public void Execute(object stateInfo)
{
    // Execute the action associated with the timer.
    _action();

    // If the timer has been running for less than 120 seconds, return.
    if (!((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).TotalSeconds > 120))
        return;

    // Set IsTimerStarted to false since the timer has stopped.
    IsTimerStarted = false;

    // Dispose of the timer.
    _timer.Dispose();
}
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to get this to work in the manner I'm hoping - basically running the service method every 15 seconds on the timer and broadcasting the stats out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to run the timer from your hub. You use an `IHostedService` run the timed operation for you and simply call the hub to send the stats.

For example:

```
public class TimerService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IQueueService _queueService;
    private readonly StatsService _statsService;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    private Timer? _timer = null;

    public TimerService(IQueueService queueService, StatsService statsService)
    {
        _queueService = queueService;
        _statsService = statsService;

        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(SendStats, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void SendStats(object? state)
    {
        var stats = _queueService.GetStats();

        Task.WaitAll(_statsService.SendStats(stats, _cts.Token));
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register this as a hosted service and .NET will take care of running it for you.

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TimerService>();
```

The timer within the service calls the `StatsService` that calls the clients with the data. This does your heavy lifting of loading the data and then calling the hub to send it out. The `IHubContext<T>` passed in the constructor is a SignalR interface that allows classes outside of a hub to send messages. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```
public class StatsService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<StatsHub> _hub;

    public StatsService(IHubContext<StatsHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

    public async Task SendStats(int[] stats, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendQueueStats", stats, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Unless you want to do something specific when the client connects or disconnects to the hub, it can be simplified down to:

```
[Authorize]
public class StatsHub : Hub
{
}
```

Information about using `IHostedService` to run a timed job can be found on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)